# Dell PowerEdge R910 adding more disks without rebooting

Tags: server, dell

I got a Dell PowerEdge r910, which has 16 disk bays, and I got eight 1 TB disks.

I am planning to have RAID 1 on disk1 and disk2. The rest of the 
disks I want to use as storage disks.

What my question is:

1) If I want to add extra disks later on without rebooting or configuring RAID.

How can I add more disks?

Answer (score 0):

If the drive bays are hot swappable, new disks should be recognized by the kernel when added.

If RAID configurations may be modified without rebooting depends on

- hard- or software-RAID
- if hardware RAID, may the controller be managed by tools while running the system?

If you use software raid (for the data disks) it could be expanded by `mdadm --grow`. Another way is to use LVM to increase/resize logical volumes. Or to use ZFS for the data disks, which is also expandable in some way without reboot.